# Can Obfuscated code refer to unobfuscated code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, obfuscation

I was wondering if I can obfuscate a part of my JS code and have it still refer to a set of consts or variables that I have set previously and will not obfuscate along with the remainder of the code. Is that possible, and if not, are there any alternatives to keeping the majority of my function code masked in some way and leaving the simple variable and consts to be out in the open?

I've tried obfuscating the code myself, however it seems that it refuses to run properly, or at all. So I'm not sure if I have messed up along the way or not.

Comment: you can create an object reference but I want to remind you that `Obfuscated` code is of no use to seasoned programmers (I could even write an `obfuscated` decompiler)

Comment: @TachibanaShin Thanks for the heads up! This is more towards regular internet users rather than programmers, I don't think anything will stop a seasoned programmer from tampering with my code if they would want to honestly.

Comment: your problem can be solved by creating a function that takes a variable value